# Class extends using functions inside render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm looking for a way to reduce code redundancy through class extending/inheritance on JavaScript/react.js.

For example, I want to have two types of UserCard components, that both represent a user's info, but one is for detailed (normal) view, other one is for list (mini) view. (e.g. imagine the normal one is something you may see on `/user/:id` and mini one is on `/users`)

Specifically, I wanted to have, for the normal ones, 1. its username and bio, icon, etc 2. its latset posts 3. extra actions (e.g. following/DM), and for the mini ones, exclude the 2. and 3. from the normal UserCard.

To implement the above model I thought I should use a JS extends or something (I'm not very familiar with `extends`), so basically I tried something similar to the following.

I know the following doesn't work, but I really don't have a good idea to how. What should I do with the issue? Thanks.

```js
class UserCardBase extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      page_size: 3,
      newly_order: true,
    };
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    {/* gets the user data */ }
    axios.get(`/api/users/${this.props.id}`)
      .then((response) => { this.setState({ user: response.data, updated: true, }); })
      .catch((error) => { console.log(error); toast.error(() => <>failed.</>); });
  };

  render() {

    const renderBlogcards = (props) => {
      {/* renders blogcards */ }
      return this.state.posts?.map((post, i) => <BlogCard key={i} data={post} />)
    }

    const extraActions = (props) => {
      {/* enables follow/message */ }
      return <div className="card__user-actions">
        <button className="card__user-actions-follow">Follow</button>
        <button className="card__user-actions-message">Message</button>
      </div>
    }

    // mini sized usercard
    const ContentMini = (props) => (
      <>
        <div className="__user_card">
          <div className="card" >
            <main className="card__user">
              <img src={this.state.user?.userprofile.avatar} alt="" className="card__user-image"></img>
              <div className="card__user-info">
                <Link to={`/user/${this.state.user?.id}`}><h2 className="card__user-info__name">@{this.state.user?.username}</h2></Link>
                <p className="card__user-info__desc">{this.state.user?.userbio.bio}</p>
              </div>
            </main>         
          </div>
        </div>
      </>
    )

    // default sized usercard
    const Content = (props) => (
      <>
        <div className="__user_card">
          <div className="card" >
            <main className="card__user">
              <img src={this.state.user?.userprofile.avatar} alt="" className="card__user-image"></img>
              <div className="card__user-info">
                <Link to={`/user/${this.state.user?.id}`}><h2 className="card__user-info__name">@{this.state.user?.username}</h2></Link>
                <p className="card__user-info__desc">{this.state.user?.userbio.bio}</p>
              </div>
              <extraActions />
            </main>
            <renderBlogcards />            
          </div>
        </div>
      </>
    )

    return (
      <>
        {/* by default, uses the mini usercard */ }
        <ContentMini />
      </>
    );
  }
}

class UserCard extends UserCardBase {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        {/* assume trying overrides the render so uses the normal usercard replacing the mini */ }
        <Content />
      </>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: You could just create a second component, for the mini info, and then return that component in your return statement within main component render. I use functional components, easier to create mini components and then include them in main component

Comment: What do you mean by a second component? you mean something like creating `class UserCardMini extends Component { ..`? The concept here is I mean not just for the mini/normal problem, but something more general. For example I'm thinking what if I need not but "UserCard" and "UserCardMni", but also `UserCardRenderBlogcards`, `UserCardExtraActions`, `UserCardBlahBlahWithBlah` and so on. In this case I believe while being able to use/compose `renderBlogcards`, `extraActions`, `BlahBlah`, `Blah` by just extending the class then modifying the render() -> return is the best option I can think of.